# Re-using an existing GtkTreeView

Tags: c++, gtk, gtktreeview

**TL;DR:** `assertion 'VALID_ITER (parent, tree_store)' failed`. How do I fix it?

I've successfully displayed a GtkTreeView in my application with the following (trimmed) code:

```
enum { DISPLAY_COLUMN, N_COLUMNS };
GValue comment = G_VALUE_INIT;
GValue amount = G_VALUE_INIT;

GtkTreeIter toplevel, child;
GtkTreeStore *treestore = gtk_tree_store_new(N_COLUMNS, G_TYPE_STRING);

for(int step = 0; step < recipe_count; step++) {
    g_value_init(&comment, G_TYPE_STRING);
    g_value_set_string(&comment, recipe[step].comment);
    gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &toplevel, NULL);
    gtk_tree_store_set_value(treestore, &toplevel,
        COMMENT_COLUMN, &comment
    );

    g_value_init(&amount, G_TYPE_STRING);
    g_value_set_string(&amount, recipe[step].amount);
    gtk_tree_store_append(treestore, &toplevel, &child);
    gtk_tree_store_set_value(treestore, &toplevel,
       COMMENT_COLUMN, &amount
    );

    g_value_unset(&amount);
    g_value_unset(&comment);
}

gtk_tree_view_set_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(app->step_tree),GTK_TREE_MODEL(treestore));

GtkCellRenderer *renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
GtkTreeViewColumn *column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes ("Step",
                                    renderer,
                                    "text", DISPLAY_COLUMN,
                                    NULL);
gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(app->step_tree), column);
```

All of the above is wrapped up in a function, so that I can load new data again later. However, the second time I try to

```
(recipe_editor:11451): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_tree_store_append: assertion `VALID_ITER (parent, tree_store)' failed
(recipe_editor:11451): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_tree_store_set_value: assertion `VALID_ITER (iter, tree_store)' failed
```

I know this means there's something wrong with my iterator(s), but I'm not sure how to actually fix it.

Comment: What does this have to do with c++?

Comment: I'm writing it in c++.

Comment: You should probably show the code that actually uses the iterators.

Comment: @SørenSandmann added code that's being used with the iterators

Comment: The answer I posted was deleted for no apparent reason, so I'll reply here. The error messages you get are consistent with passing an uninitialized iter as the parent argument, which is what you do in the code you posted. If you are "fairly certain" (as you say in the deleted comment) that you are not doing that in your actual code, then post the code that *actually* produces the error messages you are getting.

Comment: COMMENT_COLUMN should be DISPLAY_COLUMN or vice-versa?

Comment: @SørenSandmann It was deleted by a moderator (Robert Harvey), but there doesn't seem to be a reason for it.